# Solve differential equation $(1+x^2) \frac{dy}{dx} - 2xy = x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms

Solve differential equation $$(1+x^2) \frac{dy}{dx} - 2xy = x$$

I simplified it to $$\frac{1}{1+2y} dy = \frac{x}{1+x^2} dx$$

$$ \int \frac{1}{1+2y} dy =\int \frac{x}{1+x^2} dx $$

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{2}{1+2y} dy = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{2x}{1+x^2} dx$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \ln | 1 + 2y | = \frac{1}{2} \ln | 1+x^2 | + C $$

From here, I got stuck. I have to remove y from here to solve it.

The answer in the textbook gave $ y= (k(1+x^2) - 1)/{2}$ I believe $k$ is the integration constant. How do I remove the $\ln$ from both sides?

Comment: Take the antilogarithm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solving the equation $$\ln(1+2y)=ln(1+x^2)+C$$ for $y$ we get
$$y=\frac{e^c}{2}(x^2+1)-\frac{1}{2}$$ now substitute $$k=\frac{e^C}{2}$$

Comment: does $e^(\ln (1+ x^2) ) = 1 + x^2$ ? Why ?

Comment: We have $$e^{\ln(x)}=x$$ since $\ln(x)$ is the inverse function of $$e^x$$

Comment: Alright. Thanks.. got it now

Answer (score 1):

You got : $\quad\frac{1}{2} \ln | 1 + 2y | = \frac{1}{2} \ln | 1+x^2 | + C $ 
$$\frac{1}{2} \ln | 1 + 2y | - \frac{1}{2} \ln | 1+x^2 | = C  $$
$$\ln | 1 + 2y | - \ln | 1+x^2 | = 2C  $$
$$\ln \frac{| 1 + 2y |}{ | 1+x^2 |} = 2C  $$
Thus $\quad\frac{ 1 + 2y }{  1+x^2 }=$constant. 
$$\frac{ 1 + 2y }{  1+x^2 }=c$$
$$1+2y=c(1+x^2)$$
$$y=\frac12\left(c(1+x^2)-1\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

First double both sides to delete the halves, then exponentiate. Thus $k=\pm\exp 2C$, the sign being due to removing the modulus signs.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the ln on both sides just do $e^{ln|1+2y|}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{1+2y} dy = \frac{x}{1+x^2} dx$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \ln | 1 + 2y | = \frac{1}{2} \ln | 1+x^2 | + \frac {1}{2} \ln C$$

$$ | 1 + 2y | =C(1+x^2)$$

$$ 2y = -1 +C(1+x^2)$$

$$ y = \frac {-1 +C(1+x^2)}{2}$$